# Python nested dict comprehension with sets

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Can someone explain how to do nested dict comprehensions?

```
>> l = [set([1, 2, 3]), set([4, 5, 6])]
>> j = dict((a, i) for a in s for i, s in enumerate(l))
>> NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

I would have liked:

```
>> j
>> {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1}
```

I just asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638889/python-nested-dict-comprehension) about a simpler dict comprehension where the parentheses in the generator function were reduced. How come the `s` in the leftmost comprehension is not recognized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reverse the order of the two loops:

```
j = dict((a, i) for i, s in enumerate(l) for a in s)
```

Comment: This works. However I read in the manual (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) that "Special care has to be taken for the nested list comprehension: To avoid apprehension when nesting list comprehensions, read from right to left." Why doesn't this apply?

Comment: @Jasie Because what we are doing here is not nested list comprehension. Nested list comprehension is like `[ [i*j for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]`. The tool we use here is not list comprehension at all, it is a generator expression.

Comment: From PEP 202 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), according to the BDFL: `The form [... for x... for y...] nests, with the last index varying fastest, just like nested for loops.` The point isn't which type of expression we are using, it is the nested-for-loop syntax of the list comprehension.