# Dictionary comprehension nested for loop not working as planned

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested-loops

I have the following python code:

```
print {a:b for a in [1, 2] for b in [3, 4, 5]}
```

which I would expect to give me something like this:

```
{1:3, 1:4, 1:5, 2:3, 2:4, 2:5}
```

But it instead gives me this:

```
{1: 5, 2: 5}
```

I've also tried it with the loops reversed like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638949/python-nested-dict-comprehension-with-sets):

```
print {a:b for b in [3, 4, 5] for a in [1, 2]}
```

But it still gives me that wrong answer.
And I've also tried the same comprehension in a list like so:

```
print [(a, b) for a in [1, 2] for b in [3, 4, 5]]
```

Which works exactly as expected.

What am I missing about dictionaries?

FYI, `python` command returns:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:32:33) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
```

Comment: Keys are unique in dicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries have unique keys.  You can't have the key `1` (for example) mapping to multiple values.

If you need to store multiple values against a key, store a list of values rather than a single value.

Comment: @blaineh: :-)  We've all been there.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing about dictionaries?

The keys are unique.  You can read about dictionaries in the docs here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict